# PCA covariance matrix

Tags: python, numpy, pca

I am running a PCA decomposition on a covariance matrix `(2308, 2308)` in order to find out the eigenvectors/eigenvalues. I append the code below:

```
r_matrix = np.matrix(r_mean)
r_matrix.T
SR_matrix = (r_matrix.T * r_matrix) * (1/361) #covariance matrix
SR_matrixx = pd.DataFrame(SR_matrix) #dataframe
eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(SR_matrix)
```

I received the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-488-5406aac4c7cd>", line 1, in <module>
    eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(SR_matrixx)

  File "/Users/FabioMassimo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 1305, in eig
    _assertFinite(a)

  File "/Users/FabioMassimo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 217, in _assertFinite
    if not (isfinite(a).all()):

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Any solution?

Comment: aren't you sending a dataframe to np.linalg.eig ? do you use np.linalg.eig(SR_matrix)  or np.linalg.eig(SR_matrixx) ?

Comment: @jAguesses What would be the difference? Both would come out as a numpy array to eig().

Comment: I tried with both, but I always get the same error!

Comment: Hey, Josh...apparently it's working! I got strange values but it's working! Thanks